# How to upload Woocommerce product images via API?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api, python

I am using Python lib to automate product uploading. I am looking at Woocommerce Rest API documentation and I could not find a way to upload products while [creating one](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?python#create-a-product). All it assumes that product image is uploading and a URL is set in `images` parameter. Is there any other way to automate it? All I want is to upload images in gallary.